# how continue numbered list in confluence?

Tags: list, confluence

I am not sure if it is the right place to ask such question, but I need to figure out how create list style in Confluence. I have a ready numbered list, but numbers are typed as simple text. How can I change numbers into list style. I tried to enter # with intend before new item, but it puts 1. for each item from my list.

How can I make so number was putting sequentially?

Comment: Please confirm what version of Confluence. Is this Confluence version 5?

Comment: 5.5.2 confluence version

Answer (score 12):

For Confluence 5.7.4 I had to enter code after a numbered item, but you can place an image as well using this technique.

By using Shift+Enter I was able to create a line in my document that is un-numbered.  You can do this multiple times.  Then below that section I pressed return again to re-start the numbered list where it left off.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a numbered list with # but you have to pay attention that there is no blank between. For example:

```
# Point number 1
# Point number 2
# Point number 3...
```

Than it works.

But when you go this way:

```
# Point number 1

# Point number 1

# Point number 1...
```

It doesn't work.

Hope this answer your question

Comment: Thanks, so as I understand there is no possibility to make list if items are not one by one without tabs

Comment: At my opinion not.. 
Only if you write the numbers bevore... :( sorry

Comment: Perhaps surprisingly, this works great for Jira such that code blocks can be inserted between commands: simply don't add any extra newlines and the list will continue numeration after the block.

Answer (score 0):

If the content isn't on a Confluence page then you can use Insert Wiki Markup (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) to past in your list, then put the wiki markup in front of the list items as needed.

In the latest versions of Confluence it shows a preview of what the content will look like before it is inserted into the page. Latest version also allows for joining lists in the editor using backspace and delete.

```
#    for a list of numbered items
##   for second indent 
*    for bullet point
**   for indented bullet points
&nbsp;
***  and so on
```

You can select existing content from a wiki page, copy it, then use Insert > Markup to do the list again.

`&nbsp;` in the wiki markup will force a space on a list within the list.

Answer (score -1):

On the editor toolbar there is a button for adding numbered lists, a button for bullet lists, and a button for check lists. That's the easiest way to add a numbered list.

Alternatively, if you start to type out a numbered list, it should automatically create one. So if you type "1. something" then it will automatically indent it and when you hit the return key it will create "2. " and so on.

Comment: I know that, but I have a big text with numbered paragraph created not via confluence nuumbered list and I do not know how change it into confluence numbered list in easiest way

Comment: Ok, how is your numbered list created? Is it on an html page? You should be able to copy and paste it. Just high light your list, copy it, and paste it in the confluence rich text editor.